# How to keep IP address when ethernet cable unplugged linux?

Tags: networking, iptables, ip, bridge, ethernet

My board has **wlan0, ppp0 and eth0 interfaces** and I always want to keep my IP address on eth1. How can I do this?

Comment: Generally you configure applications that are dependant on other applications/services running on the same host to connect via the  reserved loop-back IP-address `127.0.0.1` or the IPv6 address  `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` or `::1` which will remain up and available when you unplug the network cable.

Comment: Don't rely on DHCP. It'll keep the address if the network is configured statically. However, I am not sure it will keep also local route to that address (the thing which makes Linux think it "owns" the address).